# TabIndex wrong sequence order

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have a slight problem in the sequence of my `tabindex` route. Theoritically, I would need just on hit on tab key to jump from one element to another, but it doesn't

I have the following HTML code :

```
<div>
  <input class="location_input_inrest_dish_pages" type="text" placeholder="Look up for a city" id="myAnchor1">
  <a href="#" title="Search" id="myAnchor2">
    <button class="search_icon_container" >
      <p class="go_text_in_search">Go!</p>
      <img class="search_icon_restpage" src="../../static/wm/images\searchicon_30x30_red.png">
    </button>
  </a>
  <a href="#" title="Locate me!">
    <div class="around_me_icon_container">
      <img class="locateme_icon" src="../../static/wm/images\target_30x30_whitev1.png">
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="large_map_in_restaurants">
  <div id="map">
  </div>
```

and following JS at the end of the document:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("myAnchor1").tabIndex = "1";
document.getElementById("myAnchor2").tabIndex = "2";
}
</script>
```

I have used [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_tabindex.asp) bit of JS to try to control the "route" of tabs so that when i am on the `Input` element, when hitting the tab key, i will land directly on the "go!" `button`, and then I can press enter.

However, problem that i have is that somehow, from the `input` element,  I need to hit the tab  key **twice** before "landing" on the `button` element, instead or just one hit...as you would expect .

Comment: Why do you have a `<button>` element *inside* an `<a>` element? I think you'll find that that's the problem.

Comment: @nnnnnn, why is that a problem? could you post a link for an article that explains it?

Comment: @nnnnn hey, you're right, silly mistake..I had kept the "A" because before the "button"  was a div....and forget to remove the "a"